# Writing and Reading file async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, .net-4.5

I want to write some content into a local file and then represent it in a textblock. I have two methods, CreateFile and Output, the first method uses WriteTextAsync method to write content into file, and the second method uses ReadTextAsync method to read the content. I called the two methods one by one, like

```
CreateFile(data);
Output(file);
```

file is a global variable, CreateFile method will write the “data” into file, and Output method output the content of it.
Unfortunately, it not always work, sometimes, I got exception which said “Object reference not set to an object”, after researching, I found sometimes, the file is null, I think it may caused by Output method is executed, but the file creating doesn’t complete. So if I add a breakpoint, it always works. Anyone can help me how to let the Output method execute after the file creating completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the reasons might be that **the file has not been created yet**, when the second method tries to read it:

[image: Diagram 1]

So, the second method have to **wait for the first method to finish**:

[image: Diagram 2]

There are several ways to achieve that.

One of them would be using [**Task Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.aspx) from [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and its [**Wait Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx):

```
var task = new Task(() => CreateFile(data));
task.Wait();
```

Another one, for example, [ManualResetEvent Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

> **ManualResetEvent** allows threads to communicate with each other by signaling. Typically, this communication concerns a task which one thread must complete before other threads can proceed.

A few other related links:

- A great article on [Joseph Albahari's website](http://www.albahari.com/) about multithreading in C#: http://www.albahari.com/threading/
- [C# Frequently Asked Questions: Using Async for File Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/23/using-async-for-file-access-alan-berman.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since your methods call asynchronous methods, a simple fix is to call your methods like this:

```
await CreateFile(data);   // This waits for the method to complete before continuing.  
Output(file);
```

Comment: @MatthewRz: The `windows-8` tag implies C# 5.0.